# Is my implementation of Generlized Pencil-of-Function correct?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, algorithms, parameter-estimation

I have a time-series data that should be of the form
$$
f(t) = \sum_nA_n(e^{\alpha_n t}+e^{-\alpha_n(T-t)});\;\alpha_n=\eta_n+i\omega_n;\;i=\sqrt{-1}
$$
and I want to find parameters $A_n$, $\eta_n$, and $\omega_n$ for $n=0,\ldots,M$. $T=64$ and $t=0,\ldots,64$.

I have already performed a fit to the parameters by using scipy.least_squares. However I would like to incorporate Bayesian priors into this fit by extracting these parameters using an alternative method, [Generalized Pencil of Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_pencil-of-function_method) method.

At the bottom of this post is my implementation. I think I have the correct dimensions of my ndarrays, and that I have followed the prescription correctly. The only issue is that I am not
sure how to interpret the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $[Y_1]^+[Y_1]$ and $[Y_1]^+[Y_2]$.
$$
[Y_1]^+[Y_2]p_i=z_ip_i;\;[Y_1]^+\text{pseudo-inverse of }[Y_1];\;z_i=e^{\alpha_i}
$$

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                           
import scipy.linalg as scilin                                                                                                                                                
import h5py                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                             
h5file = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')                                                                                                                                           
tdata = h5file['tdata'][:]                                                                                                                                                   
ydata = h5file['ydata'][:]                                                                                                                                                   
h5file.close()                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                             
# ydata is of the form sum_n A_n(e^{alpha_n*t} + e^{-alpha_n(T-t)})                                                                                                          
# tdata = [0, 1, ..., T=64]                                                                                                                                                  
# ydata = [y_0, y_1, ..., y_T]                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                             
# cut my data in half to suppress e^{-alpha_n(T-t)} terms                                                                                                                    
tdata = tdata[:32]  # shape (32,)                                                                                                                                            
ydata = ydata[:32]  # shape (32,)                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                             
L = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]                                                                                                                                                 
M = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                             
Y = np.array([np.roll(ydata[:L[0]], -j) for j in range(32-L[0])])                                                                                                            
# Y shape (32-11, 11)                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                             
U, sigma, Vh = scilin.svd(Y, full_matrices=False, lapack_driver='gesvd')                                                                                                     
# U shape (32, 11); sigma shape (11,); Vh shape (11, 11)                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                             
sigma_p = np.diag(sigma)[:, :M[0]] # sigma' shape (11, 2)                                                                                                                    
Vh_1p = Vh[:M[-1], :-1] # [Vh_1]' shape (2, 10)                                                                                                                              
Vh_2p = Vh[:M[-1], 1:]  # [Vh_2]' shape (2, 10)

Y1 = U.dot(sigma_p.dot(Vh_1p))                                                                                                                                               
Y2 = U.dot(sigma_p.dot(Vh_2p))                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                             
Y1plus = scilin.pinv2(Y1)                                                                                                                                                    
Y2plus = scilin.pinv2(Y2)                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                             
Y1mat = Y1plus @ Y1                                                                                                                                                          
eig_1, vecs_1 = scilin.eig(Y1mat)                                                                                                                                            
# Y1mat * p_i = p_i                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                             
Y2mat = Y1plus @ Y2                                                                                                                                                          
eig_2, vecs_2 = scilin.eig(Y2mat)
```

Comment: This does not look like a signal processing question to me -- could you clarify what the context is, or maybe migrate this to crossvalidated.se or a more appopriate site?

Comment: The context is that I generated some time-series data from a Monte-Carlo simulation and want to extract parameters of the signal as defined above. Since Generalized-Pencil-of-Function method is used for people extracting parameters from some signal, I figured this would be a good place to post it.

I'll migrate this to cross-validated. Thanks for the suggestion.